# ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer switch case de c++ en consola visual basic?

Tags: c, basic

```
while(contador <= 15)
{
       factor *= contador;

       switch(contador){
          case 1:
               f1 = factor;
               break;

          case 2:
               f2 = factor;
               break;

          case 3:
               f3 = factor;
               break;

          case 4:
               f4 = factor;
               break;

          case 5:
               f5 = factor;
               break;

          case 6:
               f6 = factor;
               break;

          case 7:
               f7 = factor;
               break;

          case 8:
               f8 = factor;
               break;

          case 9:
               f9 = factor;
               break;

          case 10:
               f10 = factor;
               break;

          case 11:
               f11 = factor;
               break;

          case 12:
               f12 = factor;
               break;
          }


       contador++;
       }
       printf("e^%.0f = %.9f", x, 1.0 + (x/f1) + ((pow(x,2))/f2) +
          ((pow(x,3))/f3) + ((pow(x,4))/f4) + ((pow(x,5))/f5) + 
          ((pow(x,6))/f6) + ((pow(x,7))/f7) + ((pow(x,8))/f8) +
          ((pow(x,9))/f9) + ((pow(x,10))/f10) + ((pow(x,11))/f11) +
          ((pow(x,12))/f12) );
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Hola, la sentencia switch se puede traducir a Visual Basic con una sentencia Select

Comment: hafid, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sentencia switch se puede traducir en una sentencia Select

```
Select Case contador
    Case 1
        f1 = factor
    Case 2
        f2 = factor
    Case 3
        f3 = factor
    Case 4
        f4 = factor
    Case 5
        f5 = factor
    Case 6
        f6 = factor
    Case 7
        f7 = factor
    Case 8
        f8 = factor
    Case 9
        f9 = factor
    Case 10
        f10 = factor
    Case 11
        f11 = factor
    Case 12
        f12 = factor
End Select
```